# Corrupted site collections

Tags: central-administration, site-collection, stsadm

I ran a stsadm -o enumsites and received 2 error messages in the output.  It generates the error: The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003).  I know the URL of one of the site collections from doing some web part testing.

I cannot trace down the other site collection.  enumallwebs shows nothing for the one collection I know of.  The sites do not show up as orphaned.

I'm at a loss as to how to identify these sites and remove them from the configuration database I presume.

Comment: I've tried everything in this MSDN post and the issue still persists, the symptoms seem identical.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/d345c0f0-a1b6-4d17-bc35-597c36d48dda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out what the issue was.  The site was a particularly large site restore that was deleted from the web ui in our test farm.  I believe the delete timed out and left a bit of bad data hanging out in the SiteMap table.

[This blog post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jjameson/deleting-large-sites-and-recovering-from-the-failed-deletion-of-a-site) lead me to finding where the particular site collection was located.  Once I had that content database isolated, I deleted it from Central Administration and and added it back into the farm as described [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d345c0f0-a1b6-4d17-bc35-597c36d48dda/cant-delete-a-site-collection?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy).  This cleaned up the corrupted sites.